# Full installation of tensorflow (all modules)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this repository with me ; https://github.com/layog/Accurate-Binary-Convolution-Network . As requirements.txt says, it requires tensorflow==1.4.1. So I am using miniconda (in Ubuntu18.04) and for the love of God, I can't get it to run (errors out at the below line)

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorial.* import input_data
```

Gives me an ImportError saying it can't find tensorflow.examples.  I have diagnosed the problem that a few modules are missing after I installed tensorflow (Have tried all of the below ways)

```
pip install tensorflow==1.4.1

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow==1.4.1

#And various wheel packages avaliable on the internet for 1.4.1
pip install tensorflow-1.4.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Question is, if I want all the modules which are present in the git repo source as my installed copy, do I have to COMPLETELY build tensorflow from source ? If yes, can you mention the flag I should use?  Are there any wheel packages available that have all modules present in them ? 
A link would save me tonnes of effort!

**NOTE**: Even if I manually import the examples directory, it says tensorflow.contrib is missing, and if I local import that too, another ImportError pops up. There has to be an easier way I am sure of it

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference for others stuck in the same situation:-
Use latest tensorflow build and bezel 0.27.1 for installing it. Even though the requirements state that we need an older version - use newer one instead. Not worth the hassle and will get the job done.

Also to answer the above question about building only specific directories is possible. Each module consists of BUILD file which is fed to bezel.

See the names category of the file to build specific to that folder. For reference the command I used to generate the wheel package for examples.tutorial.mnist :

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --incompatible_load_argument_is_label=false //tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist:all_files
```

Here all_files is the name found in the examples/tutorials/mnist/BUILD file.